# How to optimize layer weights in Tensorflow 2.0 with random starting points

Tags: python, tensorflow

To avoid local optima, I want to randomly pick some sets of weights and choose the best one to run the optimizer on so that it is less likely to fall in a local optimum.

Or another choice would be to run the optimizer on each set of weights and then pick the best.

My model looks as follows:

```
class model(Model):
    def __init__(self, input_dim=2, dtype=tf.float64):
        super(model, self).__init__()

        self.length_scales = Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'random_uniform',
                             bias_initializer='zeros',
                             bias_constraint=constraints.max_norm(0.),
                             activation='linear',
                             name='hp')
    @tf.function   
    def call(self, x):
        x_embedd      = self.length_scales(x)
        return x_embedd
```

However, I'm not sure how to do it in a way that is more computationally efficient, for example without completely reinitializing the model.

My application is also Gaussian processes and not necessarily deep learning.

Comment: Periodically save your model weights, then load them back when you want to "restart" from a certain point back in time.

Comment: @GPhilo I don't want pick the weights from an earlier time, but ranther pick the weights from a random set of weights.